# File is empty, but shows one byte size

Tags: bash, shell-script

My script uses a tmp file where it writes and deletes data. I use redirections to write, and `sed` to delete.

At some moment, I want to check if the file exists and is empty, but my code fails (the file exists and has no data):

```
[[ -s /tmp/tmp_file ]] && echo "not empty" || echo "empty"
not empty
```

When I check the file size, it shows 1 byte, despite that the file has no data in it.

If I open the file with gedit and save the file, then it shows 0 byte size.

Why is this happening?

How to be sure that, deleting contents, no extra byte is left?

---

Added outputs of `ls -ld` and `od`, when the file is "empty" (one byte):

```
ls -ld tmp_file
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1 dic 18 15:43 tmp_file

od tmp_file
0000000 000012
0000001
```

Image showing the one byte size:

[image]

Image of the file opened in gedit:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -ld` and `od` on the file in question when it's in the state where you think it's supposed to be empty but is not?

Comment: How do you know that it is empty (show in question)?

Comment: @Kusalananda updated the question with the commands required.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor updated question.

Comment: That file contains a single newline character (it is a file with one empty line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to take a guess that you are using `echo` to write to the file, which is appending a newline character and when you delete with `sed`, you are not matching the newline when deleting.

There are a few options here:
1: use `printf` or (`echo -n` if supported) to write without trailing newlines.
2: match the trailing newlines with sed to remove it/them.
3: Steve's method of emptying file when appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I use `echo` to add new lines, `echo -n` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

1 byte file, containing a \n only.

Use `>/tmp/foo` to zero it.

```
$ ls -l /tmp/foo
-rw-rw-r--. 1 steve steve 1 Dec 18 12:50 /tmp/foo
$ od -c /tmp/foo
0000000  \n
0000001
$ >/tmp/foo
$ ls -l /tmp/foo
-rw-rw-r--. 1 steve steve 0 Dec 18 12:51 /tmp/foo
$
```